# How to make a binned mean graph here?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, bin

I have the followed data.frame:

```
P  value
1 -1.68376331
0.99 -0.41567108
0.96  0.23841294
0.96 -0.22990539
0.96 -0.09554575
0.955  1.67393163
0.82 -0.62701762
0.81  1.32506612
0.81  0.10928334
0.78  0.55526814
0.78 0.22339582
0.70 -0.70335192
0.69  1.34438953
0.68 -0.09821771
0.67  0.33202775
```

I want to plot the mean values of every group of three (in order of P column) values. I would like them plotted along the x-axis so that the first group mean calculated is the far left point, the second group mean is the second farthest left point, etc. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Can you pass on your data so we can copy/paste it into our R sessions? What happens for groups that don't have three values, like 0.955?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
ggplot(d, aes(V1, V2)) +  geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", colour = "red", size = 2, geom = "point") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line")
```

[image]

But why not using a simple boxplot for this issue:

```
boxplot(V2 ~ V1, d)
```

You could add the means using points for instance:

```
means <- aggregate(d$V2, list(d$V1), mean)
points(means$x, col="red", pch=18)
```

Your data

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 0.99, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.955, 0.82, 
0.81, 0.81, 0.78, 0.78, 0.7, 0.69, 0.68, 0.67), V2 = c(-1.68376331, 
-0.41567108, 0.23841294, -0.22990539, -0.09554575, 1.67393163, 
-0.62701762, 1.32506612, 0.10928334, 0.55526814, 0.22339582, 
-0.70335192, 1.34438953, -0.09821771, 0.33202775)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```